# Ticker class call in C++ mbed

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

I'm writing a programme that generates a fixed frequency using a ticker in mbed environment. I'm still at the begineing so it's a little bit messy.

Comment: `Ticker flipper;` in the `Speaker` constructor is a local Automatic variable. It shadows the global `flipper`, replacing it inside the constructor. This local variable is operated on and then destroyed at the end of the constructor, leaving the global `flipper` unchanged. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://os.mbed.com/docs/v5.10/mbed-os-api-doxy/classmbed_1_1_ticker.html#a9bd57da154ea4898f7b5ae0cb992d8db), `attach` is supposed to receive a pointer to a function that can be used as a callback. Instead of providing the function, the program seems to be calling it. If you update your question with the `callback` function someone may be able to guide you to the correct usage.

Answer (score 2):

In the `attach` line change `&this` to `this`. `this` is already a pointer to self, you don't need to take the address.

```
flipper.attach(callback(this, &Speaker::flip), 0.5/frequency);
```

Comment: Thank you, it compiled. The problem now is that there is no sound coming out of the speaker. Only the click of it turning on. I will investigate.